# Opening Django project in Visual Studio Code -> projectname/bin/python file missing

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

Warning - beginner here.

I've recently switched from using Sublime Text 3 to Visual Studio Code to manage my Django projects. However, i've run into git problems due to my projectname/bin/python file not opening in Visual Studio Code (I can see that it does not appear in the explorer). I've noticed that my python3.6 file also does not open.

In Visual Studio Code, if i select File -> Open File and attempt to manually open projectname/bin/python i get an error stating "The file cannot be accessed by the system".

[Screenshot - VSC on the left, ST3 on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXiGb.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have your /bin folder inside of your project and want to commit the python binary to your git repository.

Leaving aside why, because I don't see a reason to ever include the python binary in a repository, my guess as to why the `bin/python` and `bin/python3.6` do not show up/are not openable is, that they're just symbolic links to the actual binary that is located somewhere else.

You can check this in the terminal by typing `ls -lah` into the builtin terminal of VSC in the `bin` folder.

A sample output from me looks like this:

```
$ ls -lah /opt/local/bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root   73 Oct  1 18:01  python2 -> /opt/local/bin/python2.7*
-rwxr-xr-x    2 root  14K Oct  1 09:56  python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root   24 Jan 22 13:47  python3 -> /opt/local/bin/python3.7*
-rwxr-xr-x    2 root  14K Dec 30 09:56  python3.7
```

Take note of the `l` in the beginning of some of the lines signaling, that these entries are symbolic links which point to a different location (where is in my case displayed after the `->` in the end)

I'm still wondering why you would want your python binary in the git repository in the first place though.